# Show 2 different view on select Tag on one view from controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: database, asp.net-core, view, return, location

I have a view that has 2 option for edit and create form on controller.
Now I want to control view for edit and create from.
It is about show of city and state.
If form was create I want to show a select tag for shoe location Id

If form was edited I want to show a select tag for both city Id and State Id

Now  I want to know how can I control it in view. Create and edit work fine but when I want check it separate I have problem

These are my view and controller:

View

State

```
                               <select id="Location_Id" class="form-control">


                                   @if (state.Any())
                                   {
                                       @foreach (var item in state)
                                       {
                                           <option value="@item.LocationId">@item.Title</option>

                                       }
                                   }
                               </select>
                               <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>

                               <label>City</label>
                               <select asp-for="LocationId" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control ">
                      


                                   @foreach (var item in city)
                                   {

                                       <option value="@item.LocationId ">@item.Title</option>

                                   }

                               </select>
                               <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>
                           </label>
```

If was edited change to :

```
 <label class=" w-100 d-flex align-items-center" for="">
                                <label>State  </label>

                                <select  id="Location_Id" class="form-control">

                                    @if (state.Any())
                                    {

                                        @foreach (var item in state)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.LocationId">@item.Title</option>

                                        }
                                    }

                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="StateId"></span>

                                <label> City </label>

                                <select asp-for="CityId" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control">


                                    @foreach (var item in city)
                                    {

                                        <option value="@item.LocationId ">@item.Title</option>

                                    }

                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="CityId"></span>
                            </label>
```

And this is my controller:(post method)

```
  [HttpPost("userInfo/first-start-userInfo/{packageId}"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpsertStartUserInfo(UpsertStartUserViewModel createStartUser)
  {
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();
        var res = await _packageService.UpsertUserInfoByUser(createStartUser, userId);
       
        return View(createStartUser);
    }
```

and this is my view model:

```
 public long PackageId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Sex Sex { get; set; }

    public Marriage Marriage { get; set; }

    public string Goal { get; set; }

    public long? LocationId { get; set; }

    public long? CityId { get; set; }

    public long? StateId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @hasti.au,  Both of the edit and create works, but you want to combine them to one view, so did your requirement now is do not know how to judge when should create or edit?

Comment: Yes for first question. second one : How to handle it on view. how can I check for show create and edit. when I show create form, when edit  form?

Comment: which property must be checked. check with location Id , edit is ok , but create has error":"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."